# Select List Hover Drop Down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking at the answers on: [jQuery Drop Down Hover Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775860/jquery-drop-down-hover-menu)

First, thanks so much for the answers provided there.  I was able to implement this within a constantly evolving tool at work that I use to provide the users an easier way to to their job.

However, I had a question that I didn't want to list as an answer on the previous forum... that's not how the forum should be used.

On this tool (that I mentioned above), there are also some `<select>` dropdowns in this tool that the users have stated they'd like to have the dropdowns drop on mouse-over.  So I modified this code to show this:

```js
$(".DDM").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul, select').stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul, select').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DDM">
  <select class="DDM">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

It's not working so I guess my first question is:  Is it possible to do select list hover dropdowns without changing the from `<select>` to `<li>`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of items and adjust the size:

```
$('.DDM').hover(function(){
var count = $(this).children().length;
$(this).attr('size', count);
},
function(){
$(this).removeAttr('size');
});
```

You may have to limit on the size if you have too many options.

Comment: thank you!  I really appreciate the help!  The more that I learn from you guys the less questions I feel like I need to ask.  So I appreciate the help without any backlash.  I've experienced that on previous questions.

Comment: No problem, everyone starts from somewhere, and this is what this site is about. Some people forget they have been in the same situation once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very commonly you will see dropdown menus created using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, but the same functionality can come with `<div>` or `<select>`(with adjustments). You should pick one method and stick with it until you have more experience with these kind of interactions. Try,

```
 $(".myClass").on( {
    'mouseenter':function() { $('#myMenu').slideToggle(); },
    'mouseleave':function() { $('#myMenu').slideToggle(); }
});
```

This toggles the dropdown which includes the child elements.